# React.js: How do you implement search functionality?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I managed to fetch data from **API**. Now  I want to get a specific data from search input without click.I guess I need here **filter function**. I managed to listen to input from clicking. But how to get data?
Any help will be appreciated. 
Here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CountryListCard from "./CountryListCard";

import "./CountryList.scss";

export default function CountryList() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setData(result))
      .catch((err) => console.log("error"));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  function handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          className="input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="search country ..."
          value={search}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        {data &&
          data.map((country) => (
            <div className="CountryList" key={country.name}>
              <div className="CountryListImg">
                <img src={country.flag} alt="" width="80px" />
              </div>
              <div className="countryName">{country.name}</div>
              <div className="population">{country.population}</div>
              <div className="region">{country.region}</div>
              <div>
                {country.languages.map((language, languageIndex) => (
                  <div key={languageIndex}>{language.name}</div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setData(result))
      .catch((err) => console.log("error"));
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);

function handleChange(e) {
  setSearch(e.target.value)
}

return (
  <div>
    <input
      className="input"
      type="text"
      placeholder="search country ..."
      value={search}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
    {data &&
      data.filter(item=> item.name.includes(search)).map((country) => (
        <div className="CountryList" key={country.name}>
          <div className="CountryListImg">
            <img src={country.flag} alt="" width="80px" />
          </div>
          <div className="countryName">{country.name}</div>
          <div className="population">{country.population}</div>
          <div className="region">{country.region}</div>
          <div>
            {country.languages.map((language, languageIndex) => (
              <div key={languageIndex}>{language.name}</div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Near duplicate of my answer, but doesn't handle casing, i.e. I search for "turkey", it won't match "Turkey".

Answer (score 1):

You can filter in-line when rendering the data. Remember to do case-insensitive string comparisons

```
data
  .filter(
    (country) =>
      !search || country.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
  )
  .map(country => ...)
```

If the search is falsey, i.e. `""` the filter returns true and country is returned, otherwise the country's name is checked if it includes the search value.

To save the input value

```
function handleChange(e) {
  const { value } = e.target;
  setSearch(value);
}
```

[image: Edit react-js-how-do-you-implement-search-functionality]

Answer (score 0):

First, install lodash if you don't have

```
npm install lodash
```

And use debounce

```
// Lodash here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

export default function CountryList() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const fetchData = (text) => {
// Fix your API with text search here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setData(result))
      .catch((err) => console.log("error"));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  function handleChange(e) {
    setSearch(e)
    onSearch(e)
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
  
  const onSearch = debounce((text) => {
      fetchData(text);
  }, 500)

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          className="input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="search country ..."
          value={search}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        {data &&
          data.map((country) => (
            <div className="CountryList" key={country.name}>
              <div className="CountryListImg">
                <img src={country.flag} alt="" width="80px" />
              </div>
              <div className="countryName">{country.name}</div>
              <div className="population">{country.population}</div>
              <div className="region">{country.region}</div>
              <div>
                {country.languages.map((language, languageIndex) => (
                  <div key={languageIndex}>{language.name}</div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```